# How to grab specific object metadata info from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I want to:

1. Access all GCP projects linked to my google account.
2. Get all buckets that contain the word `foobar` in their name.
3. Retrieve some of the metadata from the ones provided by Google (`Creation time, Update time, Storage class, Content-Length, Content-Type, Hash (crc32c), Hash, ETag, Generation, Metageneration, ACL, TOTAL`) for example `Creation time` and `Content-Type` and `TOTAL`.
4. Save the results in a .csv / dataframe format with fields like: `foobar, Creation time, Content-Type, TOTAL`

I don't want to:

1. Although I think only files have metadata, in case sub-directories have metadata too, I don't want to grab sub-directories' metadata.
2. Overdo it with the parsing through folders. Some of the buckets have tons of subdirectories. I want the cheapest way possible to get to the objects of interest.

What I have so far:

1. I use `gcloud projects list` to get all projects linked to my account.
2. I manually create a .csv file with the fields: `project_id, recursive, selected`. `recursive` `TRUE` is for those I know they don't have that many folders so I can afford to look through all sub-directories. `selected` `TRUE` just helps me to go through some of the projects and not all.
3. For all the projects where the `selected` field is `TRUE` I collect the data and save it in a file with the following command:
   `gsutil ls -L -p "${project}" gs://*foobar* >> non_recursive.csv`
4. For all the projects where the `selected` and the `recursive` fields is `TRUE` I collect the data and save it in a file with the following command:
   `gsutil ls -r -L -p "${project}" gs://*secret* >> recursive.csv`

So my questions:

1. How can I modify this: `gsutil ls -L -p "${project}" gs://*foobar* >> non_recursive.csv` to collect only some of the metadata fields and to output it in the dataframe format mentioned above?
2. Is there a better way to do the above? (Python or Bash solutions only please)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of the files for which you want to fetch metadata, and then generate a `gsutil ls` command for each, e.g.,

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/gsutil ls -L \1/' objects_to_list  | sh
```

If there are a large number of such objects you could do the listings in parallel, e.g.,

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/gsutil ls -L \1/' objects_to_list  | split -l 100 - LISTING_PART
for f in LISTING_PART*; do
  sh $f > $f.out &
done
wait
```

Comment: Does your answer cover the 1st question?

Answer (score 0):

This gets filename and mimeType:

```
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(BUCKET)
for blob in blobs:
    item = {'content': "gs://{}/{}".format(blob.bucket.name,blob.name), 'mimeType': "{}".format(blob.content_type)}
    print(item)
```

Can get other [metatdata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples).